# Pointer Access Violation issue

Tags: c++, pointers

i know a ton of these questions appear, but i have tried/searched everything to no avail.

**UPDATE START**

Test Class

```
#include "stdafx.h"

#include "testerClasser.h"

Tester::Tester(){

}

void Tester::GetNum(int * num){

    int num2 = 6;

    *num = num2;// error thrown here

}
```

an example of calling GetNum function

```
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{

    int* num = NULL;

    Tester* tester = new Tester();

    tester->GetNum(num);

    return 0;
}
```

error Unhandled exception at 0x77c115de in Tester.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x00000000.
**UPDATE END**

i have a method

`void CCCamera::getEyeXYZ(float *pEyeX, float *pEyeY, float *pEyeZ)
{`

```
*pEyeX = m_fEyeX;
*pEyeY = m_fEyeY;
*pEyeZ = m_fEyeZ;
```

}

i have tried to call the method

```
float* pEyeX = new float(10);
float* pEyeY= new float(10);
float* pEyeZ= new float(10);
this->m_pCamera->getEyeXYZ (pEyeX,pEyeY,pEyeZ);
```

and

```
float* pEyeX;
float* pEyeY;
float* pEyeZ;
this->m_pCamera->getEyeXYZ (pEyeX,pEyeY,pEyeZ);
```

even

```
    float pEyeX;
float pEyeY;
float pEyeZ;
this->m_pCamera->getEyeXYZ (&pEyeX,&pEyeY,&pEyeZ);
```

their is obviously something i am missing can anyone help ?

Comment: What is happening with each of these? (Both the first one and the last one seem perfectly fine, even though I'd rather take references instead of pointers)

Comment: you're de-referencing null pointers in the second block, which will definitely cause problems

Comment: Since you are using c++, consider using references instead of pointers

Comment: @ryanbwork: The second block is dereferencing *uninitialized* pointers, not null pointers (assuming they are declared as local variables).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the following code you are trying to dereference a `NULL` pointer inside `GetNum` function.

```
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{

    int* num = NULL;

    Tester* tester = new Tester();

    tester->GetNum(num); //will result in NULL pointer dereference inside GetNum!

    return 0;
}
```

What you need is most likely the following:

```
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    int num = 0;

    Tester* tester = new Tester();

    tester->GetNum(&num); // pass a pointer to local variable

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So what's the question?

The first block works, the second block does not (pointers pointing 'nowhere', which doesn't actually exist in programming so they are just pointing to more-or-less random locations), the third block is fine again.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing to do would be to figure out which pointer is causing the issue. The symptoms that you reported strongly suggest that there's something wrong with your `this` or `this->m_pCamera` pointers. Trying to play with parameter `pEye...` pointers will make no difference because they probably have nothing to do with the issue at all.